# using OR, AND Operator in denodb@v1.0.40

Tags: deno, denodb

I am working with deno and using denodb ORM and I am trying and looking at documentation from last couple of hours how to use ORM and after sometime I am stuck that how to query the following sql query using denodb ORM?

query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from table WHERE field1 = 1 AND field2 = 2 OR field3 = 3`

I am confused how to use OR, AND, etc Operator using this denodb package.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

They are not implemented as of this time. See [eveningkid/denodb#197](https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/issues/197).

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative, I suggest exploring the modules published in the GitHub organization [`denodrivers`](https://github.com/orgs/denodrivers/repositories), (e.g. [`deno.land/x/postgres`](https://deno.land/x/postgres)). However, if you're using SQLite, I suggest looking at [`deno.land/x/sqlite`](https://deno.land/x/sqlite) ([GitHub](https://github.com/dyedgreen/deno-sqlite)).

Comment: ORM can be a convenient pattern, but libraries which utilize traditional SQL string statements are more readily available across environments and give you full control of the engine you're using.